# вместо русских букв каракули в Visual Studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode

совсем недавно начал писать код на c++ решил написать простой код для вывода строки вначале на англ потом на рус с англ все нормально а с русским выводом вывело непонятные символы

```
#include <iostream>
// комент типа
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Привет мир!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

зарание спасибо!